# Floating point arithemtics bigger or equal

Tags: c#, floating-point, precision, biginteger, floating-accuracy

I would like to know, if floating point numbers in c# can give incorrect results regarding to bigger or equal.

```
static bool foo()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int i = r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue), 
        j = r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue), 
        k = r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue), 
        l = r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);

    BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(i) * j, b2 = new BigInteger(k) * l;
    double d1 = (double)i * j, d2 = (double)k * l;
    return (b1 >= b2 && d1 >= d2) || (b1 <= b2 && d1 <= d2);
}
```

More specifically, Can `foo` ever return false?

Comment: These might turn out to be two separate questions

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I really want to know what are you trying to accomplish with these piece of "code"?

Comment: This is just a POC; the main task is to find the maximum of a lot of products. BigInteger is way slower than double, so, if the code always returns true, i could use double to compute the approximate values of the products, and only compute the perfect, altough much slower BigInteger value, if the double value is bigger or equal than the current maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to rephrase your question.
Assume **a** and **b** as two integer which **a >= b**. and **da** is double representation of **a** and **db** is double representation of **b**.

Is it possible that  **da < db**?

The answer is no.
if **da < db** then **db** is a double representation of **a** with lower error than **da** which is not possible due to [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard.

So the answer to your question is also **NO** and `foo` always returns true.